# Comparing two times in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am writing an online test website in asp.net. I want to add the feature in which of setting the time limit of paper say 20 min. After fixed time the page should be redirected to result page

Comment: Please also check "Timer control in asp.net Web Application".

Answer (score 0):

Refresh document every 30 seconds:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head>
```

Set it according to 20 minutes and On Page_Load compare  the Time at first load and refresh, if TimeSpan >=20 min then redirect to another page.